# Magento 2 - Minified static files not used

Tags: magento2, theme, static-content

I enabled the setting to minify and merge JS & CSS. When I run static-content:deploy it does generate files with a .min.(css|js) appendage and the file contents are minified.

However, when I load either front end or adminhtml, it is requesting the none minified files.

Anyone know why it’s doing it?

Thanks

Comment: which mode you are using ?

Comment: production mode

Answer (score 0):

You need also flush cache after this.

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Did that. It's also a completely fresh server instance & installation from composer.